# Why didn't Miles's spider sense work before?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-verse* Miles, after being bitten by the radioactive spider, met Gwanda. Then why didn't his spider senses work to detect that Gwanda is one of his kind i.e., a spider woman (in the hair stick scene)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's most likely that he hadn't developed it at that time. In the scene where he goes to look at the spider, it shows him getting a wave of his spider-sense, which he had likely never seen before that point.

Comment: I dont agree as because in the next scene his spider senses detected that spider man is one of his kind while fighting Green Goblin

Comment: Yes, but he just got his spider-senses

Comment: On the same day later night his spider senses sensed spider man

Comment: @Harshit exactly. _after_ he developed his senses, he was able to use them, but not before

Comment: @Harshit Wasn't that from Peter Parker's perspective? It was Parker who said "Woah, you're like me"

Comment: @AzorAhai Yeah and in that scene, their spider senses were active i.e. spider senses of both got active at that time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it was because his spider sense only warms him of danger, not allies.  Like when Nick fury is able to surprise Spiderman (by lying in wait) in the Far From Home trailer.

Comment: But, Later, Gwanda did say that her spider senses detected one like her kind.